# Find CSS or Xpath for following by text of button in SeleniumWebDriver

Tags: css, selenium, xpath

Hello Can some one help me to find css or Xpath for SeleniumWebDriver.

[need to find xpath or css bt text "Update password"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeB0c.jpg)

I would really appreciate help, I would like to learn by this example too.

Thank you.

Comment: Show how you tried to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try xpath something like this:

```
$x("//*[contains(text(), 'Update password')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//*[contains(text(),'Update password')]
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the `DOM` image that you have attached yo your question, what you can do to click that `Update Password` `button`:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-primary")).click()`

Hope it helps.